# How do you skip a City Ranged Attack in Civilization 6?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civilization (edit: pre any patches) 6 I want to skip the opportunity to City Range Attack a unit because I want to do it next turn with a unit.

Is this possible? In Civ 5 you could simply right click on the attack icon (this doesn't work). Can find nothing online.

thx.

Edit - screenshot of the situation
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In later patches you appear to be able to just right click on todo items to pass on them (as in civ v).

Comment: To expand on this a bit, there is a small City Ranged Attack notification circle on the right-hand edge of the screen. That's what you right-click.

Comment: There's also an option to stop it blocking next turn (or not) in game options now

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I solved it by disabling the Auto End Turn.  The city attack symbol still appears on the map but the symbol in the bottom right corner of the screen is the End Turn Arrow instead of the City Attack symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You can go onto "options" in the top right corner, and then go to "city ranged attack turn blocking" and disable that.

Answer (score 0):

Patch [1.0.0.167]

My situation was a hidden Nuclear submarine was adjacent to my encampment. One of my naval units revealed the hidden sub.

The message and exclamation mark symbol on the end turn control was forcing me to make my encampment ranged strike. But there was no red dot on the encampment to perform the action.

I believe this is a bug and the only way I could get to the next turn was to save and reload.

Comment: did you try right clicking on the unit to skip the attack?

Comment: I tried clicking everywhere thinking it may trigger the encampment attack. Same for right click. I remember trying every mouse combination including clicking on the encampment and then clicking on the sub as if it would trigger the encampment attack